# How to make sense of left/right roundabout exits in PrivateTransportActionType?

Tags: javascript, json, here-api

I am creating the navigation manager in HERE maps by using javascript for the learning purposes. I can make sense of 18 maneuver action types (PrivateTransportActionType) such as depart, arrive, leftRamp, etc. I managed to match and display the images/icons for those 18 action types based on the maneuver data for the purpose of navigating the user.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-type-enumerations.html

I couldn't find any reference related to the 24 roundaboutexit (left/right) action types. Based on my understanding, the roundabout exits could be matched up with the clock positions but the data is still unclear to me.

I did check the other map API's but I am having difficulty in understanding these 24 action types provided by HERE maps. Moreover, HERE maps doesn't provide any data regarding the roundabouts and the kind of roundabout which is ahead in the planned route.

// For example:

const actionInfo = {"depart": "direction_depart.png", 
            "continue": "direction_forward.png"};

When the particular maneuver action ("depart/continue/arrive") is read from the JSON response in my javascript while navigating, the navigation manager notifies the user with an action (as an image in the navigator panel) before reaching the next maneuver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routing can only provide the "exit number" to take in a roundabout. Each roundabout's shape is different, so the icon to display can only be created by actually looking up the actual roundabout from the map data. Usually for a roundabout, information about the exit number is sufficient and a guidance component looks up the map data to provide context specific icons. Hence routing cannot provide you this information.

Below is an example for a roundabout which skewed:

http://www.ats-american.com/wp-content/uploads/projects/philippe-parkway-1st-avenue-northchurch-street-roundabout.jpg

Depending on which side a user is coming from, "the 3rd exit" will have a very different angle that he will have to turn. So we cannot match 4th exit with an icon.It will have to be identified based on the specific situation by the navigation component

**Note**: Roundabouts only have exits "going out". If there is a turn "inwards" then we do not call it a roundabout
Example: http://weirdthoughtsihave.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/TSR.jpg. 
This is not a roundabout in our maneuver generation. Hope this helps!